# Redirect non-existant urls to another url on Plesk Godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am fairly new to this, I have a plesk server where I have hosted PHP code.

One of my directories are - 
`mydomain.com/testing/index.php`

What I want to do is, for any url which starts with `mydomain.com/testing/` I want them to redirect to above `index.php`
for example - `mydomain.com/testing/box/2398` or `mydomain.com/testing/circle/457` both should redirect to `mydomain.com/testing/index.php`

Now I don't even know whether I need to use `.htaccess` file or `web.config` file here, and where to put these files.

So I created this `web.config` file to start with, and put it in the httpdocs/ folder -

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="^deeplink/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>   
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It can be wrong as I don't have any idea what would apply here actually.

Comment: If you want to add voting commentary or advice, please add it to the comments - it is not really of interest to most readers, who do not sign in or vote. It is especially not ideal to add it to the start of questions, since that will affect the question precis used on the front page.

Comment: nature of the question is such that people perceive it as a naive question, and despite understanding that a newbie could face such trivial problems, they downvote, and don't even provide a reason.
Nevertheless, I agree with your point that it should be added in comment. (I have tried adding comments before as well, still people don't provide reasons, Thanks for leaving note, you are a good Samaritan)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it -

Godaddy's Plesk uses IIS as their server, hence it will use a web.config file.

this is the configuration I used -

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="myredirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
                <match url="^deeplink/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/deeplink/index.php" />
            </rule>   
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

this configuration will make sure all urls coming from `hostname/deeplink/any_url_text` will always get redirected to `/deeplink/index.php`